# Crm Update productsubstitutes gets 502 error within logic app

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to update existing `productsubstitutes` entities in Dynamics CRM Online within a Logic App.

I make lookups on the products that should be linked and than use the connector to send the following data:

```
{
"host": {
    "connection": {
        "name": "/subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/dynamics_crm_dev"
    }
},
"method": "patch",
"path": "/datasets/XXX.crm4/tables/productsubstitutes/items/ITEMID",
"retryPolicy": {
    "type": "None"
},
"body": {
    "ItemInternalId": "ITEMID",
    "_productid_value": "1f2017c1-b9e8-40db-9e15-c890b127e7b2",
    "_salesrelationshiptype_label": "Interchangeable",
    "_substitutedproductid_value": "4e1d1dd7-b9e8-40db-9e15-c890b127e7b2",
    "direction": 0,
    "productsubstituteid": "839229d1-b9e8-40db-9e15-c890b127e7b2",
    "interchangability": 928350000,
    "type": 928350000
}
```

This results in the strange error message:

```
"statusCode": 502,
"headers": {
    XXX
},
"body": {
    "error": {
        "code": 502,
        "source": "logic-apis-westeurope.azure-apim.net",
        "clientRequestId": "XXXX-XXX-4b5c-a4d5-XXXX",
        "message": "BadGateway",
        "innerError": {
            "status": 502,
            "message": "The other row for the product relationship is not available.",
            "source": "XXXX.crm4.dynamics.com",
            "errors": [],
            "debugInfo": "XXXX-XXX-4b5c-a4d5-XXXX"
        }
    }
}
```

Both product IDs: 4e1d1dd7-b9e8-40db-9e15-c890b127e7b2 and 1f2017c1-b9e8-40db-9e15-c890b127e7b2 are correct and where obtained via lookups before the update requests.

This problem is reproducible, and as it looks its only happening on particular products.

Edit:

I rebuilt the update within a small C# component with the XRM SDK and I am getting the same error.
So its definitely crm related.

Edit2:
I have a MS ticket open they are aware of the issue.. and will come back on it on the 23.08 days.

Comment: You mean record specific issue?? It’s working for other records..?

Comment: It doesn't work for other records, just another error message: "A record with matching key values already exists.".... on an update event with the sdk.